# Random Forest Regression MAPE Divide by Zero error after MinMax Scaling

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

To increase the accuracy of the Random Forest regression model I changed the scikit learn standard feature scaler to MinMax scaler. During standard scalar, I did not get the error. The accuracy increased but the while calculating MAPE I am getting below error.

```
Mean Absolute Error: 0.03
Accuracy: -inf %.

__main__:5: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
```

The code is:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc_X = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)
sc_y = MinMaxScaler()
y_train = sc_y.fit_transform(y_train)


#MAE
errors = abs(y_pred - y_test)
print('Mean Absolute Error:', round(np.mean(errors), 2))

# Calculate mean absolute percentage error (MAPE)
mape = 100 * (errors / y_test)
# Calculate and display accuracy
accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape)
print('Accuracy:', round(accuracy, 2), '%.')
```

Comment: The scaler seems to have produced a value of zero, has it scaled the data's original min to max as zero to one?

Comment: Yes @JamesPhillips it has scaled some values to zero. Any idea how to handle such scenario during calculating MAPE metric?
    min(y_test)
    Out[27]: array([ 0.])

Comment: It might be possible that MAPE could give acceptable results without scaling the dependent variable, that is worth a try.

Comment: Yes @JamesPhillips without scaling and standard scaler MAPE does not encounter any issues. But only if scale using MinMax scaler MAPE has this issue. Thanks for your help James!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's one of the problems of using MAPE. From Wikipedia:

> Percentage forecast accuracy measures such as the Mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) rely on division of y_t, skewing the distribution of the MAPE for values of y_t near or equal to 0. This is especially problematic for datasets whose scales do not have a meaningful 0 or for intermittent demand datasets, where y_t=0 occurs frequently.

As an alternative, I'd suggest using [MASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_scaled_error) instead. MASE should be able to handle your problem just fine.